# How to get Google MyMaps to respect refreshable Network Links

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-mymaps, kml-network-link

I import a simple NetworkLink file (as represented immediately below) into MyMaps, calling out some level of refresh mode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <NetworkLink>
    <name>My Placemark</name>
    <Link>
      <href>http://foo.com/pm.kml</href>
      <viewRefreshMode>onInterval</viewRefreshMode>
        <refreshInterval>60</refreshInterval>
      <viewFormat>BBOX=-170,5,-50,85</viewFormat>
    </Link>
  </NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

I serve up the `pm.kml` file as something like with a simple two (2) waypoint KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>My Waypoints</name>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Moab, UT</name>
      <Point><coordinates>-109.7333,38.5733,0</coordinates></Point>
    </Placemark><Placemark>
      <name>Bluff, UT</name>
      <Point><coordinates>-109.5589,37.2817,0</coordinates></Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

This loads great.  I see the two waypoints.  However, *any subsequent updates* to this `pm.kml` file is never reflected in MyMaps.  Not upon MyMaps site reload, nor when viewed/projected at the project-level in Google Earth.  It appears that MyMaps loads the NetworkLink once and never again, regardless of refresh requests.

Is there a way that MyMaps would respect refresh even in a long-duration?